# Constantly getting error "The term 'script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using python 3.10.7 on VS Code and often when I run my files (In the terminal using CodeRunner), it does print the output of the files but just prints the error almost every time and I want to know what it means and what I can do about it.

```
script : The term 'script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that                                                                                                                                                ncluded, verify that   
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ script -a /tmp/extension/2022911/Users/terLog
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (script:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with coderunner "`/tmp/extension/2022911/Users/terLog`" but honestly I'm very confused, it's been happening for about a month.

[SCREENSHOT OF MY VSCODE WINDOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGduB.jpg)

Comment: use the python launch config and forget code runner

Comment: Can you elaborate please, how do i use the python launch config instead of code runner, thanks

Comment: if you read the VSC doc pages for python you find it all

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You seem to be using a nonexistent cmdlet called 'script', that is what is causing the problem.

I suggest trying to use

```
python <file>.py
```

or

```
python3 <file>.py
```

, whichever works for you.

Comment: Okay thank you, when i cd into the right folder I don't get this error, neither do I get it when I run it straight from the terminal so I guess that is my solution in the long term. Still frustrating though as I have to do this every time. Also for me just ```'py <file>.py``` works, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Install python extension and use the following way(The upper right corner of the vscode interface) to run python file:

[image]